# Python/Pygame: List overwrites itself apparently

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

So I've recently started with python and I'm working on a simple 2D-minecraft-like game right now. I was trying to draw some images on a Surface using Pygame but something weird keeps happening to the (2D) Array that stores all the blocks in the world. I haven't done any random terrain generation stuff yet so I'm using this to make a completely flat world:

```py
class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, blockSprites):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.blockSprites = blockSprites

    def generate(self):
        temp = [self.air] * self.width
        self.map = [temp] * self.height
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.width):
                if(y < 50):
                    self.map[y][x] = self.dirt
```

This is the Block class and the Camera class:

```py
class Block:
    def __init__(self, blockid, textureX, textureY):
        self.textureX = textureX
        self.textureY = textureY
        self.solid = True
        self.id = blockid


from math import floor
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, worldWidth, worldHeight):
        self.x = 0
        self.xB = floor(self.x/64)
        self.y = 55*64 #test value for initial camera position
        self.yB = floor(self.y/64)
        self.zoom = 1
        self.baseWidth = 960
        self.baseWidthB = 15 #in blocks (1block = 64px)
        self.baseHeight = 640
        self.baseHeightB = 10
```

And here is the World.draw function which gets called every frame:

```py
   def draw(self, canvas, camera):
        #canvas is the pygame surface which I draw on
        canvas.fill(pygame.Color(143, 218, 239))
        for y in range(camera.baseHeightB):
            for x in range(camera.baseWidthB):
                #id=0 means"air"
                if(not self.map[camera.yB + y][camera.xB + x].id == 0):
                    canvas.blit(self.blockSprites, (x*64, camera.baseHeight - (y+1)*64), (self.map[camera.yB + y][camera.xB + x].textureX, self.map[camera. yB + y][camera.xB + x].textureY, 64, 64))
        return canvas
```

The Problem is that world.map isn't half dirt blocks and half air blocks when I call world.draw()... It's all dirt blocks... I've tried adding

```py
else:
    self.map[y][x] = self.air
```

to the end of world.generate and everything turned into air blocks...
Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: You are checking y against 50, but what is the value of self.height? Maybe it's less than 50 and thus, everything is dirt

Comment: world.height and world.width are the size of the world in block units (both 100 for now)

Comment: Where is the generate function being called?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you've a class `Item` and 2 instances `o` of `Item`:

```py
class Item:
   def  __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

o = Item('o')
w, h = 3, 3
```

The output of

```py
for r in map: print([c.c for c in r])
```

is

> ```
> ['o', 'o', 'o']
> ['o', 'o', 'o']
> ['o', 'o', 'o']
> ```

The statement `temp = [o] * w` create a list o f references to the same item `o` and the statement `map = [temp] * h` creates a list of references to the same list object `temp`.

```py
temp = [o] * w
map = [temp] * h
```

At the end each element of `map` refers to the one and only list `temp` and each element of `temp` refers to the one and only object `o`.
If the content of one inner element of the map is changed then magically all object seems to change. The reason is there is just one object `o`
and all elements from map refer to the same object.

So the output of:

```py
map[1][1].c = '_'
for r in map: print([c.c for c in r])
```

is

> ```
> ['_', '_', '_']
> ['_', '_', '_']
> ['_', '_', '_']
> ```

If a new instance of `x` of `Item` is created and a single element of `map` is changed

```py
x = Item('x')
map[1][1] = x 
for r in map: print([c.c for c in r])
```

Then all the items of on row seems to change. Note, each element refers to the same list `temp`. There are not multiple rows, there is just one row object `temp`.
If an element of `temp` is changed, then this appears to be changes in each row:

> ```
> ['_', 'x', '_']
> ['_', 'x', '_']
> ['_', 'x', '_']
> ```

You've to create a map where each element of the map is a separate instance of `Item`:

```py
map = [[Item('o') for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]
```

Note, `Item('o')` creates a new instance of `Item`.
Now the content of an element can be changed or a new object can be assigned to an inner element, because there is one separate object for each object in each row:

```py
map[1][1].c = 'X'
map[1][0] = Item('x')
for r in map: print([c.c for c in r])
```

> ```non
> ['o', 'o', 'o']
> ['x', 'X', 'o']
> ['o', 'o', 'o']
> ```

Comment: Very interesting... Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Yes I do... I know about all that reference variable stuff from JavaScript. I'm new to Python but I'm not new to coding.